# is it possible to destroy your computer by running an expensive program on a big data set?

Tags: heat

[**this**](http://www.samsung.com/global/ativ/ativbook9plus.html) is my machine.

I'm running the perceptron algorithm on a very large data set.

I'm working in a room with no air con in a hot room.

It takes a long time to process this data, there are many operations involved, my computer is getting very hot.

Is it possible to destroy my machine in this way? Or cause serious harm?

Comment: Most machines newer than 1980 have hardware protection against overheating; e.g. Intel CPUs shutting off once they reach a temperature threshold (95°C I believe). Anyways, that's off topic here as it's entirely a hardware issue and has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Possible, but quite unlikely.  You do increase very slightly the chance of a data corruption incident, requiring reinstallation of the OS and losing all your data.

Comment: @l4mpi ...it has a little bit to do with programming.

Comment: is there a seperate site for hardware?

Comment: @Yamada_Tarō there is a separate site for general computer topics called SuperUser, where this would be on topic but probably a duplicate. And no, it does not have any relation to programming except for the fact that somebody has to program the code that makes your pc run hot. You can achieve the same effect by running tools like FurMark or a Pi benchmark or thousands of other programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's depends on computer configuration. Most modern hardware has overheat protection, they just shutdown on throttle performance or otherheat. But be careful, you can just loose your calculations because of this.

Comment: why did someone down vote this answer. i really hate that you know? it's like, if someone wants to down vote an answer, i think they should have to at lest provide a reason.